# How do I ensure my JDBC source is possible to connect to from Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

I want to ensure I can connect to my JDBC-capable source, but I want to ensure my firewall rules are correctly set up to allow this.  How can I ensure my network infrastructure is correctly set up to connect?

Answer (score 0):

One way to validate this is to use an SSH session to the Agent VM and using the `ping` command (or similar `netstat` / `traceroute`) to ensure a simple route to your host is available.

This would look like:

1. `ssh` onto the Agent VM
2. Run `ping my.hostname.com:PORT`

If `no route to host` comes back, this means your firewall rules aren't correctly set up, so the Agent VM owner will need to change configuration to allow the traffic.

If a notice indicating `X bytes received from my.hostname.com` comes back, this means you can hit the host and your firewall rules are correctly set up.